# BigInt implementation - converting a string to binary representatio stored as unsigned int

Tags: c++

I'm doing a BigInt implementation in C++ and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a converter from (and to) string (C string would suffice for now).

I implement the number as an array of unsigned int (so basically putting blocks of bits next to each other). I just can't figure out how to convert a string to this representation.

For example if usigned int would be 32b and i'd get a string of "4294967296", or "5000000000" or basically anything larger than what a 32b int can hold, how would I properly convert it to appropriate binary representation?

I know I'm missing something obvious, and I'm only asking for a push to the right direction. Thanks for help and sorry for asking such a silly question!

Comment: "C string would suffice for now"… do you think that would be easier or something?

Comment: no, but since this is a homework, I am pretty much limitted in what I can use. I know that it would be easier with C++ string object, but since we have to do this conversion for the C string, I have to just go with it. Of course, I can use string internally, but the input and output have to by in cstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way (not necessarily the most efficient) is to implement the usual arithmetic operators and then just do the following:

```
// (pseudo-code)
// String to BigInt

String s = ...;
BigInt x = 0;

while (!s.empty())
{
    x *= 10;
    x += s[0] - '0';
    s.pop_front();
}

Output(x);

// (pseudo-code)
// BigInt to String

BigInt x = ...;
String s;

while (x > 0)
{
    s += '0' + x % 10;
    x /= 10;
}

Reverse(s);
Output(s);
```

If you wanted to do something trickier than you could try the following:

1. If input I is < 100 use above method.
2. Estimate D number of digits of I by bit length * 3 / 10.
3. Mod and Divide by factor F = 10 ^ (D/2), to get I = X*F + Y;
4. Execute recursively with I=X and I=Y

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement and test the string-to-number algorithm using a builtin type such as `int`.
2. Implement a bignum class with `operator+`, `operator*`, and whatever else the above algorithm uses.
3. Now the algorithm should work unchanged with the bignum class.

Use the string conversion algo to debug the class, not the other way around.

Also, I'd encourage you to try and write at a high level, and not fall back on C constructs. C may be simpler, but usually does not make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at, for instance, `mp_toradix` and `mp_read_radix` in Michael Bromberger's MPI.

Note that repeated division by 10 (used in the above) performs very poorly, which shows up when you have very big integers. It's not the "be all and end all", but it's more than good enough for homework.

A divide and conquer approach is possible. Here is the gist. For instance, given the number 123456789, we can break it into pieces: 1234 56789, by dividing it by a power of 10. (You can think of these pieces of two large digits in base 100,000.   Now performing the repeated division by 10 is now cheaper on the two pieces! Dividing 1234 by 10 three times and 56879 by 10 four times is cheaper than dividing 123456789 by 10 eight times.

Of course, a really large number can be recursively broken into more than two pieces.

Bruno Haibl's CLN (used in CLISP) does something like that and it is blazingly fast compared to MPI, in converting numbers with thousands of digits to numeric text.

Comment: Needless to say, you need some basic operations in your library first, like at least division and modulo by a small number. (Small meaning: fits into one BigInt digit.)

Comment: thanks for the tip on the efficiency, I don't think I'll have to use it on this homework, but since my school project for this semester is a calculator with an infinitive precision with floating point, which I'll base on this homework, I'll use it there.