# Override >> operator like int

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

this is part of a homework assignment. I don't want an answer just help. I have to make a class called MyInt that can store any sized positive integer. I can only use cstring cctype iomanip and iostream libraries. I really don't understand even where to begin on this.

6)  Create an overload of the extraction operator >> for reading integers from an input stream. This operator should ignore any leading white space before the number, then read consecutive digits until a non-digit is encountered (this is the same way that >> for a normal int works, so we want to make ours work the same way).  This operator should only extract and store the digits in the object.  The "first non-digit" encountered after the number may be part of the next input, so should not be extracted. You may assume that the first non-whitespace character in the input will be a digit. i.e. you do not have to error check for entry of an inappropriate type (like a letter) when you have asked for a number.

Example:  Suppose the following code is executed, and the input typed is "  12345   7894H".

MyInt x, y; 
  char ch; 
  cin >> x >> y >> ch; 
The value of x should now be 12345, the value of y should be 7894 and the value of ch should be 'H'.

The last state of my code is as follows:

```
 istream& operator>>(istream& s, MyInt& N){
N.Resize(5);
N.currentSize=1;
char c;
int i = 0;
s >> c;
N.DigitArray[i++] = C2I(c);
N.currentSize++;
c = s.peek();
while(C2I(c) != -1){
    s >> c;
    if(N.currentSize >= N.maxSize)
        N.Resize(N.maxSize + 5);
    N.DigitArray[i] = C2I(c);
    i++;
    N.currentSize++;
}
}
```

It almost works! Now it grabs the right number but it doesn't end when I hit enter, I have to enter a letter for it to end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833112/bigint-implementation-converting-a-string-to-binary-representatio-stored-as-un/9833145#9833145

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `operator>>` overload for your class this way (as a free function, not inside the class):

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& lhs, MyInt& rhs) {
    // read from lhs into rhs

    // then return lhs to allow chaining
    return lhs;
}
```

You can use the members `peek` and `read` of `istream` to read in characters, and `isspace` to test if a character is a space, and `isdigit` to check if a character is a number (`isspace` and `isdigit` are in the `<cctype>` header).

Comment: How do I get each character into an istream?

Comment: @user1289423 `cin >> myint` is the same as `operator>>(cin, myint)`, so the `istream` is `cin` when you do `cin >> myint` (when `myint` is a `MyInt`).  The characters will be in there from what the user enters into the console.

Comment: So assuming I can pick out the numbers from their stream, how do I take the series of numbers, save them in an array of ints digit by digit and then save that at the object.

Comment: @user1289423 you put the array in the `MyInt` class, and add each digit that you read from `lhs` to the array. Also in your code sample, you need to use the argument `s`, not `cin`, so that it can work on other `istream`s, like `ifstream`s.

Comment: I upadted my code to what I have now, still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @easyxtarget trace through your code to make sure the execution is how you want it. I can tell you though, the loop will execute forever because you are doing `(c = ' ')`, which is assigning to `c`. It should be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Oh, and C2I is a function that converts a char to an int if its between 0 and 9 otherwise it returns -1

Comment: @easyxtarget I would split it into two `while` loops, one that skips all whitespace, and another that reads in digit characters. And I would use `isdigit`, not your own function.

Comment: I updated it. It's better now expect the problem mentioned below my code and it taks on "-10" to then end of the inputted number

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `operator>>` should be concerned *only* with extracting the sequence of chars from the stream and knowing when to stop based on your rules for that.  Then, it should defer to a constructor of `myInt` to actually ingest that string.  After all, that class will probably want to expose constructors like:

```
myInt bigone ("123456123451234123121");
```

for more general-purpose use, right?  And, functions should have a single responsibility.

So your general form will be:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, myInt x)
{
    string s = extract_digits_from_stream(is);
    x = myInt(s);
    return is;  // chaining
}
```

Now how do you extract just digits from a stream and stop at a non-digit?  Well, the `peek` function comes to mind, as does `unget`.  I'd look at source code for the extraction operator for regular integers and see what *it* does.

Comment: Answered to serve as a reference for future readers.  It would be interesting to hear back from OP, who might be an experienced and talented programmer by now, reflecting on his learning process.