# How to effectively store large number in integer array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer

Hello everybody out there! I have a home work assigment where I need to build a high presision calculator that will operate with very large numbers. The whole point of this assigment is that storing the values in arrays as one digit goes to separate array cell is now allowed.

That is memory representation of number

335897294593872

like so

```
int number[] = {3, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 2};
```

is not legit,

nor

```
char number[] = {3, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 2};
```

nor

```
std::string number("335897294593872");
```

What I want to do is to split up the whole number into 32bit chunks and store each individual chunk in separate array cell data type of which is u32int_t.

Since I get the input from keyboard I store all values in std::string initially and later put them in integer arrays to perform operations.

How do I put binary representation of a large number into an integer array filling in all bits properly?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Using standard C++ libraries only

EDIT2: I want to be able to add, subtract, multiply, divide those arrays with large numbers so I mean not to merely cut the string up and store decimal representation in integer array, but rather preserve bits order of the number itself to be able to calculate carry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigInt implementation - converting a string to binary representatio stored as unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833112/bigint-implementation-converting-a-string-to-binary-representatio-stored-as-un)

Comment: As a simple exercise, try to do it with base 10, approx. 3.322 bits per digit.

Comment: It's not about BigInt library, I'm talking about pure c++ with no side libraries usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather naïve solution:

1. If last digit in string is odd store a 1 in result (otherwise leave it 0).
2. Divide digits in string by 2 (considering carries).
3. If 32 bits have written add another element to result vector.
4. Repeat this until string contains 0s only.

Source Code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<uint32_t> toBigInt(std::string text)
{
  // convert string to BCD-like
  for (char &c : text) c -= '0';
  // build result vector
  std::vector<uint32_t> value(1, 0);
  uint32_t bit = 1;
  for (;;) {
    // set next bit if last digit is odd
    if (text.back() & 1) value.back() |= bit;
    // divide BCD-like by 2
    bool notNull = false; int carry = 0;
    for (char &c : text) {
      const int carryNew = c & 1;
      c /= 2; c += carry * 5;
      carry = carryNew;
      notNull |= c;
    }
    if (!notNull) break;
    // shift bit
    bit <<= 1;
    if (!bit) {
      value.push_back(0); bit = 1;
    }
  }
  // done
  return value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<uint32_t> &value)
{
  std::ios fmtOld(0); fmtOld.copyfmt(out);
  for (size_t i = value.size(); i--;) {
    out << std::hex << value[i] << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof (uint32_t) * 2);
  }
  out.copyfmt(fmtOld);
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  std::string tests[] = {
    "0", "1",
    "4294967295", // 0xffffffff
    "4294967296", // 0x100000000
    "18446744073709551615", // 0xffffffffffffff
    "18446744073709551616", // 0x100000000000000
  };
  for (const std::string &test : tests) {
    std::cout << test << ": " << toBigInt(test) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0
1: 1
4294967295: ffffffff
4294967296: 100000000
18446744073709551615: ffffffffffffffff
18446744073709551616: 10000000000000000
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db66fac9bd0ef2f4)</kbd>

**Notes:**

1. The output is little-endian. (The least significant element is first.)
2. For the `tests`, I used numbers where hex-code is simple to check by eyes.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps alot.

Answer (score 1):

To use an array to store the different parts of a big number is a common way to do the work.  Another thing to think of is to consider the different architecture implementations for `signed int`s, that lead you to have to sacrifice (this is what normal libraries to deal with big integers do) to allow `signed` to `unsigned` conversions (you have several ways of doing here) between the parts of your number or how are you going to implement the different arithmetic operations.

I don't generally recommend  to use `long long` integer versions for the array cells, as they are not generally the native size of the architecture, so to give the architecture some chance to do things efficiently, I should use a reduced (at least one bit, to be able to *see* the carries out from one *extended digit* to the next) standard `unsigned` (for example, gnu **libgmp* uses 24bit integers on each array cell ---last time I checked that).  It's also common to reduce it to a multiple of `char` size, so displacements and reallocation of numbers are easier than to make `31 bit` displacements on a full array of bits.

Answer (score 0):

It's common that when you work with money or delicate numbers like that you often use Integers, because you can assure, many things of it, so my recommendation is that whenever you work with this big numbers, simulate a fixpoint or floating-point arithmetic with two Ints, so you can "watch" how everything is executing, you could check the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for the floating point. 
If you store the number in an array make sure to take a constant number of steps to make all the operations that you are doing while manipulating it. Which could be tricky.

I recommend you to trust the integers but fix the size of bits. 
But if you really want to go for interesting stuff, try and use the bit-wise operators, and maybe you could get something interesting out if it.

You could check the details of the data types [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), in particular, the `signed short int`, or the `long long int`, and to confirm sizes of the data types check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)